# Não consigo utilizar um trigger corretamente no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER inventory_update_purchases AFTER INSERT ON purchases
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE products
        SET products.inventory = products.inventory + NEW.inventory_bought
        WHERE products.product_id = NEW.product_id
END;//

delimiter ;
```

O que quero fazer é alterar o `inventory` quando chega uma remessa de fornecedores!

Já vi soluções online e fazem, literalmente, aquilo que tenho aqui.

O erro que me dá é relativamente à função de `END`:

> (Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7)

Isto parece repetitivo mas já tentei quase tudo (só falta mesmo mudar a versão do mysql, a única coisa que ainda não tentei).

Comment: Não está faltando um `;` para finalizar o comando `UPDATE`?

Comment: não porque não é o comando update(visto que estamos dentro de um trigger --> tentei fazer isso e apontou logo como erro)...eu penso que possa ser o delimitador do END mas não me dá nada...

Comment: Tenho que concordar com o @anonimo. Segundo a documentação o `;` é necessário depois de cada instrução, independentemente de ser dentro de um `trigger` ou não. Se virmos a documentação (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) apresentam inumeros exemplos de como implementar e em todos eles o `;` é usado.

Comment: Desculpem! Só pensei no ; no final.. apos colocar no where, funcionou plenamente! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reforçando o meu comentário.

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_update_purchases AFTER INSERT ON purchases
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE products
        SET products.inventory = products.inventory + NEW.inventory_bought
        WHERE products.product_id = NEW.product_id; END;
```

Fiddler aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a37486